# Why does C program give wrong output for positive integer?

Tags: c, if-statement

The below program gives correct result for negative and zero integer, but for positive integer, it gives wrong output:

```
Enter the value of a : 6
The no is positive
The no is zero
```

Why?

```
int main()
{   int a;
    printf("Enter the value of a : ");
    scanf("%d",&a);
    if(a>0)
        printf("The no is positive\n");
    if(a<0)
        printf("The no is negative\n");
    else
       printf("The no is zero\n");
}
```

Comment: when asking about a run time problem as this question is doing, always post a [mcve] so we can reproduce the problem and help you debug it.

Comment: OT:  regarding: `scanf("%d",&a);`  always check the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  (The scanf() family of functions returns the number of successful input format conversions)  In this case anything other than 1 indicates an error occurred

Comment: In general, mutually exclusive 'if()' statements should have all those after the first prefixed with `else if`

Comment: Going through that code, what makes you think that it should behave different?

Answer (score 7):

You have to write

```
if(a>0)
    printf("The no is positive\n");
else if(a<0)
    printf("The no is negative\n");
else
   printf("The no is zero\n");
```

Otherwise the two if statements are executed independly.

```
if(a>0)
    printf("The no is positive\n");
```

and

```
if(a<0)
    printf("The no is negative\n");
else
   printf("The no is zero\n");
```

and for a positive number you will get two outputs.

Answer (score 4):

Your second `if` should be `else if`. Both the first condition and the `else` get run otherwise when you have a positive number.

Answer (score 3):

It's because you are using `if` statements without following `else` blocks.  Once the first `if` is evaluated, it still evaluated the second `if` and then since that will be false if the input is positive, the `else` block will run, printing the wrong output.

Answer (score 1):

Brother you have to use else if because the code checks for the first check i.e a>0 which is true then it goes after that as no else is present it goes on to the next if block i.e a<0 which is false so it goes to else condition of that and prints the number is zero.
Inorder to avoid it consider using else if so only one block is true i.e a>0 and then the program exits the conditional statement

```
if(a>0)
    printf("The no is positive\n");
else if(a<0)
    printf("The no is negative\n");
else
    printf("The no is zero\n");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have missed the condition, to get it satisfied you have to use `if..else..if`

```
int main()
{   
  int a;
  printf("Enter the value of a : ");
  scanf("%d",&a);
  if(a>0)
    printf("The no is positive\n");
  else 
  if(a<0)
    printf("The no is negative\n");
  else
   printf("The no is zero\n");
}
```

In your case second `if` condition was failing so it was directly printing whatever there is in `else` condition Please try above code you will get correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
int a;
printf("Enter the value of a : ");
scanf("%d",&a);
if(a>0)
printf("The no is positive\n");
else if(a<0)
printf("The no is negative\n");
else
printf("zero");
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code such that others can learn from it